# Android studio: Run button not working

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When I try to run my app (my first test) for the first time, the green button shows up but the emulator does not run my app, it only works (the emulator) , and when I try again the green button( RUN) does not work.
Anyone can help ?

Comment: You need to run the Gradle `installDebug` step. It's not clear what `app` in the dropdown is trying to run

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tapped on the "Make Project" button (the hammer icon) and then the run button worked

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but some other people can still have the same issue.

I was getting the same error, and a log message somewhere said me adb wasn't found. After reinstalling platform-tools it got solved.

So try opening SDK Manager from Tools -> SDK Manager, go to SDK Tools tab and uncheck Android SDK Platform-Tools. After applying changes install it again.

Answer (score -1):

Invalidate cashe and restart worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Have you made sure you unlocked the emulator? By unlock I mean like how a phone screen is locked, the emulator does the same thing.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Even then, you should be able to run the app with your phone or emulator locked.